# character case on a Loop

Tags: loops, character, case

hope someone can help please. I was able to get the code but unable to display the characters similar to the input. I capitalized the input for comparison but output should be similar to the input. See image pls. Thanks.

```
    morse_code_dict = {
        'A' : '.-', 
        'B' : '-...', 
        'C' : '-.-.', 
        'D' : '-..', 
        'E' : '.', 
        'F' : '..-.', 
        'G' : '--.', 
        'H' : '....', 
        'I' : '..', 
        'J' : '.---', 
        'K' : '-.-', 
        'L' : '.-..', 
        'M' : '--', 
        'N' : '-.', 
        'O' : '---', 
        'P' : '.--.', 
        'Q' : '--.-', 
        'R' : '.-.', 
        'S' : '...', 
        'T' : '-', 
        'U' : '..-', 
        'V' : '...-', 
        'W' : '.--', 
        'X' : '-..-', 
        'Y' : '-.--', 
        'Z' : '--..', 
        '0' : '-----', 
        '1' : '.----', 
        '2' : '..---', 
        '3' : '...--', 
        '4' : '....-', 
        '5' : '.....', 
        '6' : '-....', 
        '7' : '--...', 
        '8' : '---..', 
        '9' : '----.', 
        '.' : '.-.-.-', 
        ',' : '--..--'
    }
    
    
    
    
    text = input("Please enter the phrase to send: ")
    text2 = ' '.join(text.split()).upper()
    for character in text2:
     if character in morse_code_dict:
         print(f"{character} in morse is {morse_code_dict[character]}")
     elif character == ' ':
         print("Gap")
     else:`enter code here`
         print(f"{character} is not available in morse.")
```

[correct output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Blq7T.png)

[incorrect output I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5qYv.png)

[image: correct output2]

Answer (score 0):

Don't convert the string to uppercase before iterating over it, you can use `.upper` inside the loop. For example:

```py
text = input("Please enter the phrase to send: ")

morse_code_dict[" "] = "Gap"

for ch in " ".join(text.split()):
    if ch.upper() in morse_code_dict:
        print(f"{ch} in morse is {morse_code_dict[ch.upper()]}")
    else:
        print(f"{ch} is not available in morse.")
```

Prints:

```
T in morse is -
h in morse is ....
e in morse is .
  in morse is Gap
l in morse is .-..
a in morse is .-
s in morse is ...
t in morse is -
  in morse is Gap
c in morse is -.-.
h in morse is ....
a in morse is .-
r in morse is .-.
a in morse is .-
c in morse is -.-.
t in morse is -
e in morse is .
r in morse is .-.
  in morse is Gap
i in morse is ..
s in morse is ...
  in morse is Gap
n in morse is -.
o in morse is ---
t in morse is -
  in morse is Gap
p in morse is .--.
r in morse is .-.
e in morse is .
s in morse is ...
e in morse is .
n in morse is -.
t in morse is -
! is not available in morse.
```

Comment: Still can't get the expected output as above (please see image labelled "correct output"). It should also print "is not available in morse." which is why I added if else on my original code.